# Equivalent of sigprocmask on Windows?

Tags: windows, signals

Is there a mechanism for masking a signal in windows similar to `sigprocmask`

Comment: There are no signals in Windows, so such a function would be redundant.

Comment: @Harry redundant to what ?

Comment: Redundant meaning "would serve no purpose".  So far as I can see, there's no point in masking signals that don't exist.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: ... on the other hand, the C runtime includes a minimal signal mechanism as required by the C standard.  They're local to the thread that raised them, which is why I supposed that masking them would serve no purpose, but on second thoughts I guess there may be edge cases.  So in that case: there is no way to mask them AFAIK, but you could set the signal handler to SIG_IGN.

Comment: The usability of this is delaying the signal handling until some other code is executed, and therefore I need to mask the signal, if I had ignored the signal then I would have alterated the behavior, which is not what I want to do.

Comment: So you want a signal raised in one thread to block until another thread has finished doing something?  I don't think there's any direct way to do that, but I suppose you could install your own signal handler to do the blocking and then chain to the previous signal handler, or modify your signal handler to block as needed.  But remember that signals aren't native to Windows, you're dealing with an emulation layer.  It would probably be preferable to use the native functionality instead.  If you tell us which signal(s) you're interested in, we might be able to provide more specific advice.

Comment: I am intereted in the non-realtime signals, I think this solution is general and not particular to a specific signal ?

Comment: I'm not sure.  If you're talking about explicit calls to raise() then there's no problem, the signal handler should be able to do whatever it likes including blocking, and I guess SIGABRT is also OK, provided you follow the rules about C runtime functions in signal handlers.  SIGINT should be fine, except that the signal handler is called in a newly created thread which might not be what you were expecting.  I'm not sure about SIGFPE, there's some odd wording in the documentation that I don't understand, along with a recommendation to use exception handling instead.

Comment: Catching SIGSEGV is probably pretty dangerous, though, because the original exception might have been raised from inside a Win32 API call.  I'm not sure what you can safely do in this case.  Blocking in particular seems likely to risk a deadlock.  (I may be mistaken about this, perhaps one of the experts can clarify.)  And that's it, those are the only signals the C runtime generates.